# Compartilhando componentes e serviços entre Modulos

Tags: angular, services, angular-module

No desenvolvimento de projetos Angular, é comum o compartilhamento de componentes e serviços entre os vários módulos que a aplicação pode ter.

Quando o assunto são serviços, projetos Angular tendem a seguir um padrão `Singleton`, ou seja, uma instância do serviço para todo o escopo.

Então por exemplo, imagine um serviço chamado `AuthService` (trata-se de um serviço de autenticação) portanto ao declarar o serviço no `providers` do `app.module`, está instância ficara disponível a toda aplicação:

```
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule 
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Caso queira utilizar está instância em algum componente, basta realizar a injeção de dependência.

Pode-se obter mais detalhes em: [Singleton services](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)

Ao compartilhar componentes, temos que utilizar o metadado `exports` ao invés do `providers` no modulo que o componentes está sendo declarado:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavBarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    NavBarComponent
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Porém, mesmo que o modulo `SharedModule` seja importado no modulo `AppModulo`, como pode ser visto a cima, ele não fica disponível a toda aplicação, sendo necessário realizar o importe do modulo `SharedModule` em cada modulo que irá utilizar o componente `NavBarComponent`.

Gostaria de confirmar se realmente este entendimento está correto, como pode ser lido neste trecho:

> Import modules when you want to use directives, pipes, and components. Importing a module with services means that you will have a new instance of that service, which typically is not what you need (typically one wants to reuse an existing service).

Disponível em: [Sharing modules](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules#using-components-vs-services-from-other-modules)

Comment: é isso mesmo tem que importar o modulo com o componente em cada modulo que for utulizalo